# Variable Footer Height

Tags: html, css-position, sticky

i have one Problem. My Footer isn't really fixed on the Bottom of the Page. So how can I realize that? I need a full responsive Footer for my Site. The Footer have to stick on the bottom of the Page in all Viewport-sizes.

Thank you for your help.

HTML/PHP:

```html
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();


$doc->addStyleSheet('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300');
$doc->addScript('http://kollektionen.testgott.de/js/ruhecollections.min.js');
$doc->addStylesheet('http://kollektionen.testgott.de/deliver.php?style=2a');


$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/main.css');


$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/plugins/slicknav.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.2.cb.min.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js');







?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <jdoc:include type="head"/>

</head>

<body>


<header>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="logo">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo"/>

            </div>
            <div class="header-data">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header-data"/>
            </div>
        </div>


</header>


<nav id="mainnav">
    <div class="nav-wrap">


        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav"/>
    </div>

</nav>


<nav id="menu2">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu2"/>

</nav>

<div id="wrap-all">

    <div class="content-wrap">


        <jdoc:include type="message"/>

        <jdoc:include type="component"/>


        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="kontakt"/>

</div>
</div>
<footer>

    <div class="footer-data">

        <div class="footer-wrap">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="adress"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="tel"/>
            </div>




            <div class="col-md-3">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="btn"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu"/>
            </div>

        </div>




</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

SCSS/CSS:

```html
/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Oswald, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('../img/bg-beige.gif');
  background-repeat: repeat;

}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.33em;
  color: #0e7035;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2{
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#0e7035;
  font-weight: 400;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav-wrap{
  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper-mobile{
  display:none;
}

.wrapper-full{
  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  background-image: url('../img/bg-gruen.gif');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div#wrap-all {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;

}

.content-wrap {
  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;


}

.logo {
  float: left;

  padding-top: 1.5em;


    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

}



.header-data {

  ul {
    text-align: right;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: .5em 0em;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding-right: 1em;

    span {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    }
  }
}

#mainnav {
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  top: -4.15em;
  left: 0em;

}

nav{

  margin-top: .1em;

.nav-child > li:last-child{
  margin-right: 2.5em;
}

  .nav-child > li:hover:last-child{
    margin-right: 2.5em;
  }

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  float:right;
 margin-top: -0.5em

}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 25px transparent;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;

}

  ul li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
  }
ul li:hover {

  border: 1px solid #fffefc;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #fffefc;
  margin-right:2.5em;



}

  ul li:hover:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  li.current.active{
    border: 1px solid #fffefc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #fffefc;

  }

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 16em;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
  z-index: 1000;
}


  ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
ul li ul li {
  background-color:rgba(255,254,252,0.9);

  display: block;


}
  ul li ul li a{
    margin-left: .5em;
    color:black;
  }
ul li ul li a:hover {
  color:#0e7035;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;



 margin-left: 1em;



}
ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;



  -webkit-box-shadow: -25px 25px 15px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* WebKit */
  -moz-box-shadow: -25px 25px 15px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ; /* Firefox */
  box-shadow: -25px 25px 15px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Standard */
}
}



.content {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 3.5em;

  .intro {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left
  }

  .intro img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.33em;
    color: #0e7035;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  p {
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  .check-box {
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      color: #0e7035;
    }

    li {
      font-weight: 100;
      margin-bottom: .5em;
      font-size: 1.15em;

      i {
        margin-right: .5em;
        font-size: 1.333em;
      }


    }

  }

}



.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}

#content{
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}


.product-content{
    h2{
      color:#0e7035;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
}

.product-img{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
float:left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;




}

.product-row{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0e7035;
}

.product-row:last-child{
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.kontakt-content{
  width: 100%;
}

.content-kontakt{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


.kontakt-data {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;


}

.kontakt-map{
 float: right;
}

footer {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px -15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-image: url('../img/bg-gruen.gif');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4{
  float:left;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

    ul{
      padding:0;
    }
}

.col-md-2, .col-md-3{
  text-align: center;
    margin-top: .6em;
    font-size: 1.5em;

}

.col-md-3{
  li{
    margin-right: 1em;
    display:inline;

  }
}

.col-md-4{
  float:right;

  text-align: right;

    ul {
      li{
        a{
          text-decoration: none;
          color:#fff;
        }
      }
      padding:0;
    }
}

.footer-data {

  max-width: 1005px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;




  li {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;

    span {

      font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    }
  }

}

.copyright-wrap {
  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;



}



/*
    Mobile Menu Core Style
*/

.slicknav_btn { position: relative; display: block; vertical-align: middle; float: right; padding: 0.438em 0.625em 0.438em 0.625em; line-height: 1.125em; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { display: none; line-height: 1.188em; float: left; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon { float: left; margin: 0.188em 0 0 0.438em; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text { margin: 0 }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { display: block; width: 1.125em; height: 0.125em; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px; border-radius: 1px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar + .slicknav_icon-bar { margin-top: 0.188em }
.slicknav_nav { clear: both }
.slicknav_nav ul,
.slicknav_nav li { display: block }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow { font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0 0 0 0.4em; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row { display: block; }
.slicknav_nav a { display: block }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a,
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a { display: inline }
.slicknav_menu:before,
.slicknav_menu:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.slicknav_menu:after { clear: both }
/* IE6/7 support */
.slicknav_menu { *zoom: 1 }

/*
    User Default Style
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of the menu.
*/

.slicknav_menu {
  display: none;
  font-size:16px;

}
/* Button */
.slicknav_btn {
  margin: 5px 5px 6px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.5em;

}
/* Button Text */
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Button Lines */
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.slicknav_menu {
  background-image:url('../img/bg-gruen.gif');

  padding:5px;
}
.slicknav_nav {
  color:#fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:0.875em;
}
.slicknav_nav, .slicknav_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slicknav_nav ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row {
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin:2px 5px;
}
.slicknav_nav a{
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin:2px 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a,
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row:hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background:#ccc;
  color:#fff;
}
.slicknav_nav a:hover{
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background:#ccc;
  color:#222;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode {
  margin-left:15px;
}

.footer-copyright {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  bottom: 0em;
  left: 0;

}

.footer-wrap{

  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;

}

.copyright {

  width: 1005px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3em;





  li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
  }
  li:first-child {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    float: left;




    font-size: 1em;
  }
  li:last-child {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1.5em;



  }
}

.control-group{
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

 .first-row{
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    float: left;
  }



textarea{
  color: #898989;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px #0e7035;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
}


.btn .btn-success{
  span {
    background: none;}
}

button{
  span{
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}

.col-sm-2 > li > a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-list > li {
    margin-right: 1em;
    display: inline;

}


#menu2 {
  display:none;
}

.icon-list  a {
  color:#fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){

  div#wrap-all {
    width:90%;
    max-width: none;

  }


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){

  body{
    font-size: .833em;
  }

  footer{

  }

  .copyright{

    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6em;

  }


#mainnav{


  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  top: -5em;
  left: 0em;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .footer-data > .content-wrap > .wrapper-full {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-data > .content-wrap > .wrapper-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 813px) {

  .copyright{
    bottom: -5.5em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){

  .content .intro{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content .check-box{
    width: 100%;


          ul{
      padding:0;
    }

  }
.logo{
  width: 100%;
}


  .header-data ul {
    float:left;
  }

#mainmenu {



}
  .menu{
    display: none;
  }

  .js .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .slicknav_menu{
    display: block;
  }

 nav ul li:hover{


   border: 1px solid transparent;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px transparent;
   margin-right: 0em;

 }

  .header-data li {
    display:inline;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 477px){

  body{
    font-size: 0.75em;
  }

  #mainnav{
    top:-5.5em;
  }




}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need fixed positioning which will position an element relative to the browser window.

```
.footer-data {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position